# Generate URL of resources that are handled by Grails AssetPipeline

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I need to access a local `JSON` file. Since Grails 2.4 implements the AssetPipeline plugin by default, I saved my local `JSON` file at:

```
/grails-app/assets/javascript/vendor/me/json/local.json
```

Now what I need is to generate a URL to this `JSON` file, to be used as a function parameter on my JavaScript's `$.getJSON()` . I've tried using:

```
var URL.local = ""${ raw(asset.assetPath(src: "local.json")) }";
```

but it generates an invalid link:

```
console.log(URL.local);
// prints      /project/assets/local.json
// instead of  /project/assets/vendor/me/json/local.json
```

I also encountered the same scenario with images that are handled by AssetPipeline1.9.9— that are supposed to be inserted dynamically on the page. How can I generate the URL pointing this resource? I know, I can always provide a static String for the URL, but it seems there would be a more proper solution.

## EDIT

I was asked if I could move the local `JSON` file directly under the `assets/javascript` root directory instead of placing it under a subdirectory to for an easier solution. I prefer not to, for organization purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `asset.assetPath(src: "/me/json/local.json")`

The assets plugin looks in all of the immediate children of `assets/`. Your local.json file would need to be placed in `/project/assets/foo/` for your current code to pick it up.

Check out the relevant documentation [here](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#organization) which contains an example.

> The first level deep within the assets folder is simply used for organization purposes and can contain folders of any name you wish. File types also don't need to be in any specific folder. These folders are omitted from the URL mappings and relative path calculations.